# How to auto-assign custom meta boxes based on post category in WordPress?

Tags: wordpress

I have several post categories and the heavily use meta boxes, and those are varying from each other. Is there a way, so I can choose a category of the post and corresponding meta boxes are automatically set in the correct order, so I can quickle fill them out?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try the [Advanced Custom Fields](http://www.advancedcustomfields.com/) plugin. It will let you create custom metaboxes and assign them to show up on certain types of posts dependent on a variety of criteria, including category.